# Stream of numbers and best space complexity to find n/2th element

Tags: java, algorithm, data-structures

I was trying to solve this problem where a stream of numbers of length not more than `M` will be given. You don't know the exact length of the stream but are sure that it wont exceed `M`. At the end of the stream, you have to tell the `N/2th` element of the stream, considering that `N` elements came in the stream. what would be best space complexity with which you can solve this problem

my solution:
i think we can take a queue of size `m/2`  , and push two element , then pop 1 element and keep on till 
stream is over . The `n/2th` will be at head of queue then. Time complexity will be min `O(n)` for any way , but for this approach,space complexity is  `m/2` .. is there any better solution?

Comment: Is this a persistent stream (say, a file), or something like a network stream in which you only have one chance to see an item if you don't store it?

Answer (score 4):

I hope it is obvious that you will need at least `N/2` memory allocation (Unless you can re-iterate through your steam, reading the same data again) . Your algorithm uses `M/2`, given the fact that `N` is upper bounded by `M` would make it look like it doesn't matter which you will choose, since `N` *can* go up to `M`.

But it *doesn't* have to. If you consider `N` being *way smaller* than `M` (for example `N=5` and `M=1 000 000`) then you would waste a *lot of* resources.

I would recommend some dynamic growth array structure, something like `ArrayList`, but that is not good for removing first element.

**Conclusion:** You can have `O(N)` both time and memory complexity, and you can't get any better.

Friendly edit regarding `ArrayList`: adding an element to an `ArrayList` is in "amortized constant time", so adding N items is O(N) in time. Removing them, however, is linear (per JavaDoc) so you can definitely get O(N) in time and space but **ONLY IF** you don't remove anything. If you do remove, you get O(N) in space (O(N/2) = O(N)), but your time complexity goes up.

Comment: @ErickG.Hagstrom: That's only true if it's a persistent stream.

Comment: @JimMischel good call. You have to store all of the objects between the current halfway point and the last one you got from the stream. I retract my statement.

Answer (score 2):

Do you know the "tortoise and hare" algorithm? Start with two pointers to the beginning of the input. Then at each step advance the hare two elements and the tortoise one element. When the hare reaches the end of the input the tortoise is at the midpoint. This is O(n) time, since it visits each element of the input once, and O(1) space, since it keeps exactly two pointers regardless of the size of the input.

Comment: But if the hare is at item 100, the tortoise is at item 50. When the hare goes to 102, item 51 better be in memory. So he has to keep at least n/2 items in memory.

Comment: Well, we don't know the nature of the stream. I am assuming that the stream is persistent.

Comment: Sure, that will work with a persistent stream. If we assume a network stream, though, or something like a magnetic tape, then this approach doesn't work.

Comment: There's nothing in the problem formulation that specifies a persistent stream. In fact, this question is interesting precisely because the OP didn't say "an array of" or "a `List` of". In the general case, given a stream, you get one shot.